# How do I execute a step based on resultset output from previous step in pentaho data integration?

Tags: pentaho

I need to update a field based on whether a client exists in some table (I'm using a sql script with the distinct function to check for this). I suppose that the Execute SQL Script will return a result-set with some records or an empty one.

How do I setup the condition to do this?

Comment: Perhaps a user defined Java class will serve the purpose better.

Comment: I ended up using a different approach with avoided the need for a condition. I also found that the _Filter Rows_ step might have led to a solution but did not explore that too far.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use the database lookup step..
You can configure that to either not pass a row if it doesnt exist, or you can configure a default value if it's not found (either null or some hard coded value)

if you dont want to do that because it's not flexible enough, then maybe "database join" or as a last resort then maybe a table input and a stream lookup.